# GStreamer - RTSP to HLS / mp4

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I try to save RTSP h.264 stream to HLS mp4 files:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://....." ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! hlssink max-files=0 playlist-length=0 location="/home/user/ch%05d.mp4" playlist-location="/home/user/list.m3u8" target-duration=15
```

As a result - there is only one file ch00000.mp4, which includes the whole videostream (3min instead of 15sec in "target-duration").

If I save to mpegtsmux / ts files - all is ok for the same command.

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

HLS consists of MPEG transport stream segments. So first: `matroskamux` does not make sense here. You will need `mpegtsmux` instead. To indicate what it really is you normally would name the files with a `.ts` extension. It may still work for GStreamer as it is just a file name - players may reject playing it because the expect another sort of file format.

E.g.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://....." ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! \
mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=0 playlist-length=0 location="/home/user/ch%05d.ts" \
playlist-location="/home/user/list.m3u8" target-duration=15
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! For my question, there is no problem with making a hls playlist of ".ts" files. The main target is to record a playlist of ".mp4" files. And the command I gave in a topic question records a video in ONE file, though there is no warnings/errors... Therefore I continue to look for a solution..

Comment: I don't know if GStreamer supports the MP4 feature of the latest HLS spec by Apple. Either way you will need to use `mp4mux` instead of `matroskamux`. Then again - I think this spec uses fragmented MP4 files. So these files have fragments in them themselves. So I don't see the point of an additional playlist. Or what makes this mode different from MPEG-DASH at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use gstreamer? Otherwise I believe this ffmpeg command does what you want.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://... -c copy -hls_list_size 10 -hls_segment_type fmp4 output.m3u8
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know that ffmpeg can solve this task simply. But I'm interested in the possibility of getting mp4-chunks from gstreamer. And as I understand, it can't...